# Update node revision programmatically don't save new value

Tags: 8

If I try to edit a review:

```
$node = node_revision_load(56);
$node->set('field', 'value);
$node->save();
```

This has no effect. The value is not changed.

The function does not make mistakes, it seems to save everything, but it is not so.

How can I do ?

Comment: The function does not make mistakes, it seems to save everything, but it is not so. It is a different question

Comment: If you don't see the changed field value, then you probably don't save into the active revision. It's very rare that you modify old revisions, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am creating a bridge to run scheduler with content moderation, so it has to work with revisions rather than content.
I want to remove all the fields "publish_on" and "onpublish_on" old to create a new revision with either of these two fields

Comment: To create a new revision call `$node->setNewRevision();` before saving and you don't need to load a revision for this, simply load the node (which gets the active revision).

Comment: Obviously, this changes the cron logic for the scheduler. Because I now recover all reviews with "publish_on" (for this I wanted to undo the others). But I understand that I have to change business logic